# Сортировка вектора

Tags: c++

Как отсортировать вектор по убыванию элементов, используя стандартные алгоритмы?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
std::sort(v.rbegin(), v.rend());
```

Answer (score 5):

Думаю будет понятно:

```
std::sort(my_vect.rbegin(), my_vect.rend());
or
std::sort(my_vect.begin(), my_vect.end(), std::greater<type>);
```

где type - тип элементов вектора (int, double, string, etc.)

Comment: std::greater<int>()